# Terraria: I lost my data / weapons and tools when I cloud saved

Tags: terraria

When I was going to my cloud save world this message popped up if I wanted to change it to local save I picked cloud save and it deleted two traps a chest with 3 stacks of pumpkin moon medallions and a godly drax an artificial tree and a couple of banners. How can I get my data back?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The latest patch notes for 1.3.0.5 recommend not saving the world to the cloud as there are currently issues with the cloud save functionality for worlds that may result in data loss.  It sounds like you hit one of these issues. The game creators mentioned that you most likely wont be able to restore any of the data and to switch to local world saves instead to prevent any further data loss/corruption along with making backup copies of your worlds while they look into the saving issues.